# Combine DataFrames with an array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

There are 2 DataFrames, df1 is defined as

```
 +----+---------+---------+
 |id  |value1   |value2   | 
 +----+---------+---------+
 |1   |["J","W"]|      0.3|
 |2   |         |      0.6|
 |3   |["n"]    |      0.7|
 +----+---------+---------+
```

df2 is defined as

```
 +----+---------+
 |id  |value1   |
 +----+---------+
 | 1  | "t"     |
 | 2  | "m"     |
 +----+---------+
```

is there an easy way to combine the DataFrame as df3

```
 +----+--------------+---------+
 |id  |value1        |value2   | 
 +----+--------------+---------+
 |1   |["J","W", "t"]|      0.3|
 |2   |["m]          |      0.6|
 |3   |["n"]         |      0.7|
 +----+--------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first `join` the two dataframes with column `value1` of `df2` renamed as

```
val joineddf = df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("value1", "value21"), Seq("id"), "left")
```

Then you should define a `udf` function to add the renamed `value21` column of `df2` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def mergeUdf = udf((array: mutable.WrappedArray[String], str: String) => str match{
  case null => array
  case _ => array ++ Array(str)
})
```

Finally you should call the `udf` function and `drop` the unnecessary columns as

```
joineddf.withColumn("value1", mergeUdf($"value1", $"value21"))
    .drop("value21")
```

You should get your desired output as

```
+---+---------+------+
|id |value1   |value2|
+---+---------+------+
|1  |[J, W, t]|0.3   |
|2  |[m]      |0.6   |
|3  |[n]      |0.7   |
+---+---------+------+
```